# Use Identityserver4 for Custom authentication to get token by OTP Mobile Number or only User Name

Tags: c#, authentication, token, identityserver4, one-time-password

I'm using Identity Server 4 and .net Core 5 Identity for authentication service
I use this Code to get Token
I have searched but a cannot any accepted solution ...

```
        // discover endpoints from metadata
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(_siteSetting.IdentitySettings.IdentityServerUrl);
        if (disco.IsError)
            throw new BadRequestException(disco.Error);
        // request token
        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = "MYClientId",
            ClientSecret = "secret_for_the_MYClientId",

            Scope = "ApiName roles",
            UserName = dto.userName,
            Password = dto.Password,
        });
```

I can get tokens by username and password
After registration, I want to Implement login with OTP

1: the user sends the phone number

2: In the backend, the OTP was generated and saved, and then will send to the mobile number by calling third party services

3: User sends the token with mobile number

4: in this step, I can find userName with mobile number
because the user registered before and check the OTP to validation

5: How can I Generate the token only by the UserName Or cell phone number and set all claims?!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and overwrite `ValidateAsync` method

and instead of checking by user and password, you can check by username and code or phone and code.
Check the below implementation and replace `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` with your implementation and Raise `UserLoginSuccessEvent` if success and `UserLoginFailureEvent` if not

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{

    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private IEventService _events;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> _logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator{TUser}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userManager">The user manager.</param>
    /// <param name="signInManager">The sign in manager.</param>
    /// <param name="events">The events.</param>
    /// <param name="logger">The logger.</param>
    public ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEventService events,

        ILogger<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _events = events;
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    //this is used to validate your user account with provided grant at /connect/token
    public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        {

            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
            if (user == null) user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(context.UserName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                // 
                var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, context.Password, true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                

                    _logger.LogInformation("Credentials validated for username: {username}", context.UserName);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(context.UserName, user.Id, context.UserName, interactive: false));

                    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.Id, AuthenticationMethods.Password);
                    return;
                }
                else if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Authentication failed for username: {username}, reason: locked out", context.UserName);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(context.UserName, "locked out", interactive: false));
                    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, "account is locked out try after 5 min");
                    return;
                }
                else if (result.IsNotAllowed)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Authentication failed for username: {username}, reason: not allowed", context.UserName);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(context.UserName, "not allowed", interactive: false));
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Authentication failed for username: {username}, reason: invalid credentials", context.UserName);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(context.UserName, "invalid credentials", interactive: false));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("No user found matching username: {username}", context.UserName);
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(context.UserName, "invalid username", interactive: false));
            }

            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);

        }




    }
}
```